# How to get geocode of particular address of Spain using google API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm try to get geocode of particular address but I get this particular error when I try with Spain address it shows me `Invalid request. One of the input parameters contains a non-UTF-8 string.` but works fine on other countries like USA or India.

I try with other Spanish address, But it continue show me same error I use this url for get geocode

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=hereputspainaddress&key=myapikey`

Also try with pass region and language code

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=hereputspainaddress&key=myapikey&language=es-co&region=ES`

I need help for how to get address of all region as per user added and get geocode of that particular address.

Comment: What is the "non-utf-8 string" you are trying to geocode?  Have you tried sending that utf-8 encoded?

Comment: I already pass using utf-8 and also send u one of address of spain "Calle Aduana, 29, 28070 MADRID, España" Can you please look into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [URL-encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the address string before sending it in the request.

I believe the issue might be with an ñ symbol in your address. If you URL-encode it it will be replaced with `%C3%B1`.

If I URL-encode the address I can get a response

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Calle%20Aduana%2C%2029%2C%2028070%20MADRID%2C%20Espa%C3%B1a&key=MY_API_KEY`

I'm getting place ID `ChIJba0n1oYoQg0R5u5-y9jZ9sU` with address 'Calle de la Aduana, 29, 28013 Madrid, Spain' in the response.

You can also see this result in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DCalle%2520Aduana%252C%252029%252C%252028070%2520MADRID%252C%2520Espa%25F1a

I hope this helps!